# postgresql how to multiplex WAL files

Tags: postgresql

In production system corruption of active WAL files would be very risky.
Is there any way I can multiplex WAL files or Control file or can restore the wal file if lost separately

Comment: Put them on RAID and have the RAID controller do it.

Comment: Postgres can detect WAL segment corruption because it uses checksums for each of them. More information about that in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-reliability.html (especially the paragraph that explains which measures are taken against file system corruption)